# I set my own path to $PATH variable to have global access to some of my scripts, but I can not access them in any directory

Tags: bash

I used `~/.bash_profile` to add a new path to my `$PATH` variable. I added  `export PATH="/usr/sbin:$PATH"` to my `~/.bash_profile`, then saved it, and typed `source ~/.bash_profile` in my terminal. I echo `$PATH` and I see that I have this path in my `$PATH` variable. But I cannot access lsof utility (this command is in `/usr/sbin` directory). Also, I have this situation with any directories. I wanted to add a directory, I added it, I had this path in my `$PATH` variable, but I could not access scripts that I have there.

Comment: Hi Dari, the sbin directory contains files which can only be run with root privileges.

Comment: I googled it, and I was looking for a way to become a root user, but I could not implement either way. As I saw from different tutorials, I needed to use sudo command, but I could not use it. I googled about this too, and I was confused by all this information. But okay, if I can not access files in sbin directory, what about other directories? I can not access any files from there.